# How to run minio cli commands from R?

Tags: r, terminal, command-line-interface, minio

I'm trying to run Minio CLI commands from R, I have tried using system(), system2() as well as the processx::run(), but I only get an error message. It works really well to do it via the terminal. For test purposes I would like to be able to run "mc --help" or "mc ls" from R-code, how do I go about it?